# wifi adapter missing from device manager

Tags: networking, windows-10, drivers, network-adapter, device-manager

Yesterday all of a sudden, My wifi got disconnected. It seems the wifi adapter is missing altogether from the device manager. I tried

1. restarting the laptop
2. re-installing the wifi drivers
3. Check hidden devices in device manager
4. Check windows 10 setting and tried resetting the network
5. Tried driver update with **Driver Easy and DriverPack**
6. Tried running netsh commands

None of the above worked. Also after successfully installing the driver and restarting the laptop. The freshly installed adapter is also not showing in the device manager.

I have gone through many posts and vlogs regarding this issue but none of them solved my problem. Please help me fix this. Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: depending on the type of laptop you have, it may not be a big deal to just pop the back off and make sure your adapter is seated firmly/connected properly

Comment: Second that, try reseating it.

Comment: I did try that but no use. Also, after about 10-15 restarts, the wifi came back on for about 10 mins and it went back to the same state. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If your laptop has a physical switch, see if it comes back after turning it on / off. If it's a "fn" + key combo switch and you have reseated, then you are most likely in need of another PCIe adapter. (They are cheap). Did this laptop suffer any physical damage near the hinges?

Comment: Thanks @Tim_Stewart, But my laptop does not have any physical switch. My laptop is Asus x541UJ. I do not have a fn combo on my laptop and there is no physical damage as well. Also, it worked fine for about 6 hours yesterday. Then I turned it off. And after I turned it on again wifi was gone again. I don't understand what is causing it.
Also, while it was worked I had to put my wifi password again.

Comment: Update: I just restarted the laptop again, and checked for hidden adapter in device manager. I can see my wifi adapter here(It was not there before, I checked). Now the properties of this driver has a code 45 error. How to fix this??

Comment: Update the drivers from the manufacturers support web site.

Comment: just did. I used Driver Easy software to do so. Driver Easy says the device is unplugged. What does that mean??

Comment: It is funny how my laptop is working right now. the wifi comes alive and dies on it's own. I used it last night for about 8 hours and now it is gone again. @Tim_Stewart I tried to update the driver this time without the Driver easy software and did it from device manager and search online for latest drivers. This also didnot work. the wifi driver is still hidden. It is getting very annoying now.

Comment: Replace it, it's either overheating or defective.

Answer (score -1):

I have personally faced this kind of problem with my previous laptop, the problem was, the drivers were not compatible with windows 10 and it constantly crashed my laptop and sometimes it even went to blue screen error.
Simple solution is to replace the wifi chip inside your laptop you can do it easily and you can get an upgraded WI-FI 6 standard chip for your laptop.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Replacing hardware isn't simple. It may be the right solution, but it isn't simple